# Find dict that has user inputted key from a list of dicts

Tags: python, json

**python 3.5**

hi i have this simple json.json file :

**json**

```
{"x": [
    {"A": "B"},
    {"C": "D"},
    {"E": "F"}
]}
```

and i have this code to find the letter after A or C or E

**python**

```
data = json.load(open('json.json'))
R = 'C' #user input
print(data['x'][1][R])
```

How can I find which dict with has the key without knowing and hard coding the index of the dict?

Comment: There is no 'A' key in the second element, so logically there would be no hit. What are you trying to do? Are you trying to search for a set with the key from `R`?

Comment: Are you able to fix the process that generates the JSON so it is in a more sensible format like: `{"x": {"A": "B", "C": "D", "E": "F"} }`?

Comment: python uses zero based indexing not one. So `data['x'][1]` is the second

Comment: that was a mistake sorry

Comment: @Phylogenesis i have another code that uses this type json code and i want to edit them i have to rewrite everything

Comment: i know it works but when R changes to A then [1] should be [0] so how should i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to find the value by searching without hard coding the index, what you need is a loop that checks each dict for the key:

```
data = json.load(open('json.json'))
R = 'C' #user input
for d in  data['x']:
    if R in d:
        print(d[R])
        break # if there can be more that one match then remove
```

Comment: No worries, I edited your question to match up with what you are actually asking.

Answer (score 0):

As Padraic Cunningham pointed out, you need to loop through your results. Your solution would look like this:

```
data = json.load(open('json.json'))
R = 'C' #user input
print([x for x in data['x'] if x.keys()[0] == R][0][R])
```

`[x for x in data['x'] if x.keys()[0] == R]` gives you all the dict with key R in a list. Assuming that you don't have repeated keys, pick the first element and access to its value.